# How to generate a dataframe (to later be exported to a CSV) in Pandas using a list of regex results?

Tags: python, pandas

I am constructing a script that utilizes regex to search through a document I wrote and pull out the name, address, and description for businesses in the document.  From there I am trying to setup a dataframe in Pandas using  a dictionary with 'Name', 'Address', and 'Description' as keys while the results from the regex would serve as the values.  The problem I am currently running into when I generate the dataframe is that the columns will correctly generate, but the results don't go into different rows.

```
import re
import socket
import csv
import pandas as pd


#read the Guide's text file
file = r'myfile.txt'
fh = open(file, encoding="utf8")

excel = r'myCSV.csv'
f = open(excel, 'w')

addList = list()
nameAddList = list()
descList = list()
nameList = list()

fhRead = fh.readlines()
for lines in fhRead:
    addresses = re.findall('\(([^()]{2,}?)\)', lines) #returns the addresses found within the parenthesis
    name = re.findall('^(.+?)\(', lines) #Returns the name 
    nameAdd = re.findall('^(.+?)-', lines) #Returns the name and addresses found within the parenthesis
    desc = re.findall('\-(.*)', lines) #Returns the description for each bar

    if len(addresses) < 1:
        continue
    else:
        addList.append(addresses)


    if len(nameAdd) < 1:
        continue
    else:
        nameAddList.append(nameAdd)


    if len(desc) < 1:
        continue
    else:
        descList.append(desc)


    if len(name) < 1:
        continue
    else:
        nameList.append(name)


nameStr = str(nameList)
addressStr = str(addList)
descStr = str(descList)

#I think what is happening here is that when I pass through the list, it reads the list as one single value
data = {'Name': [[nameStr]], 
        'Address': [[addressStr]],
        'Description': [descStr]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df[['Name', 'Address', 'Description']])
```

This is my current output:

```
 Name  ...                                        Description
0  [['Business 1 '], ['Business 2 '], ['Business 3'...  ...  [[' Description 1...

[1 rows x 3 columns]
```

An example of how I would want the code to appear is similar to this code that I found on Geeks for Geeks:

```
# Define a dictionary containing employee data
data = {'Name': [['Jai'], ['Princi'], ['Gaurav'], ['Anuj']],
        'Age': [27, 24, 22, 32],
        'Address': ['Delhi', 'Kanpur', 'Allahabad', 'Kannauj'],
        'Qualification': ['Msc', 'MA', 'MCA', 'Phd']}

# Convert the dictionary into DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# select two columns
print(df[['Name', 'Qualification', ]])
```

That block of code produces this output:

```
       Name Qualification
0     [Jai]           Msc
1  [Princi]            MA
2  [Gaurav]           MCA
3    [Anuj]           Phd
```

How can I accomplish this output with a generated list as opposed to having to hand enter in the values like in the Geeks for Geeks code?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to the loop an append method, like that:

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[Name,Age,Address,Qualification]], columns=df.columns))
```

This code will append the new line to the end of the df